# how to get share button to work in tableview cell swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift and i am creating a feed using tableviews. I have a custom table view cell which has a button and i have included a IBAction function for when the button is tapped on the cell.

```
@IBAction func didTapShareBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    // display share screen with url
}
```

1. how do i get the specific data (url) to this action?
2. how do i create a share screen - when i try to implement this i get an error stating - "Value of type 'FeedListTableViewCell' has no member 'present'"

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to try and present a share screen from **inside** your cell.

The recommended approach is to use a `closure` so your cell can tell the controller that the button was tapped, and the controller will handle the action.

Quick example - assuming you have a cell with a Label and a Button:

```
class FeedListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var btnTapClosure: ((FeedListTableViewCell)->())?

    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func didTapShareButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // tell the controller the button was tapped
        btnTapClosure?(self)
    }
    
}
```

When your table view controller dequeues the cell, we set the label text **and** we set the closure:

```
class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var myData: [String] = [
        "https://apple.com",
        "https://google.com",
        "https://stackoverflow.com",
    ]
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedListTableViewCell
        cell.theLabel.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        
        // set the closure
        cell.btnTapClosure = { [weak self] cell in
            // safely unwrap weak self and optional indexPath
            guard let self = self,
                  let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
            else { return }
            
            // get the url from our data source
            let urlString = self.myData[indexPath.row]
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
                // could not get a valid URL from the string
                return
            }
            
            // present the share screen
            let objectsToShare = [url]
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
            self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```